# Postgres: Efficient schema for querying with one exact string match and two range matches

Tags: postgresql

The table I need to query:

```sql
CREATE TABLE regions (
    state text NOT NULL,
    zip_begin text NOT NULL,  -- 9-digit zip code
    zip_end text NOT NULL,
    date_begin date NOT NULL,
    date_end date,

    data ...,
)
```

There are ~50 states and between 0-5M rows per state.  The zip and date ranges might overlap.

The following will be one of the most common queries in my OLTP application:

```sql
SELECT data
FROM regions
WHERE state = {state}
  AND {date} BETWEEN date_begin AND date_end
  AND {zip} BETWEEN zip_begin AND zip_end
```

This query usually yields one row, but may sometimes yield more.

From the Postgres docs, it sounds like a GiST index might do what I need, but I don't really understand how those work.

Comment: A standard B-Tree index on `(state, date_begin, date_end, zip_begin, zip_end)` should be enough

Comment: A B-Tree index won't work.  For example, if I query with `state` 'CA' and `date` '2020-01-01', Postgres can quickly identify the sub-range of 'CA' rows where `date_begin` is less than or equal to '2020-01-01', but it has to then check every row in that range to see if `date_end` is greater than or equal to '2020-01-01'.

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: @KannanGoudan I also agree with a_horse_with_no_name here. Unless you think after the `state` and `date_begin` filtering of the index that there'll still be millions of rows for just the subset of what's left, it's probably a non-issue once it compares the `date_end` and zip code fields, no need to get creative before you test what commonly works. The only other suggestion I'd have (but very similar to a_horse_with_no_name's) is trying a **B-Tree** index on the same fields in a different order that may yield less results sooner, that is define the index field list in order of uniqueness...

Comment: ...For example, you can try testing `(zip_begin, zip_end, date_begin, date_end, state)` or `(date_begin, date_end, zip_begin, zip_end, state)` since your `state` field is probably the least unique of them all. This improves the selectivity of the index by reducing the results sooner so the rest of the fields in the index are applied to a smaller subset of records upfront. This is also a micro-optimization and probably not needed. Also the only way to actually tell which way is best, is to test each definition.

Comment: A single index cannot do the trick. You use string comparison for the ZIP? Are you sure?

Comment: @J.D.  But the state field is the only one tested for simple equality.  That probably makes it the best one to put first, as it preserves the full utility of the following column.

Comment: @jjanes It actually depends on the cardinality of his predicates. If the zip code predicate returns less records than the `state` predicate, it *can* be more efficient being earlier in the index definition's field list (50 states is not very unique so probably returns a good chunk of records, but zip code is likely more unique and returns less records, even in a range *potentially*). Most times this is a micro-optimization though and not needed to be concerned about.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: why not? If those were OR conditions, I would agree, but with AND conditions and the first one being an equality comparison, why shouldn't the index be used to also filter on the date range?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name A single B-tree index can only support an inequality condition on a single column (and equality conditions on several). That is, it can support more inequality conditions, but only as a filter, not as a scan key.

Comment: @J.D. "Unless you think after the state and date_begin filtering of the index that there'll still be millions of rows for just the subset of what's left".  Yes, that's the problem with a B-Tree.  A single state might have 5M rows and the `date_begin >= ?` condition will (on average) only eliminate half of them.

Comment: @KannanGoundan please see my alternative indexing suggestions, which accounts for the fact your `state` predicate might have the highest **cardinality** (returns the most rows), and could help fix that. Again testing is the best way to know which works best. Especially if you're saying all the fields in your predicates do indeed return only a few rows at most, then I'd bet your zip code predicate filters a lot of that.

Comment: @J.D., as @jjanes said, the query has an equality predicate on `state`, so putting `state` first in the index "preserves the full utility of the following column".  This is not something you need to test; just think about how a B-Tree is used.

Comment: @KannanGoundan I know how a **B-Tree** works since I've been using them for indexing for a long time at this point.  You're missing my point of **cardinality** and **selectivity**. This is all we know at this point, the query you provided above is the only one we know of at this point, so the "*full utility*" is a moot point. If you're concerned about other queries as well that use `state` for predicate filtering and doesn't use `zip_end` and `zip_begin` then it no longer is a moot point, but you'd have to provide those queries as well otherwise there's no point in talking about "full...

Comment: ...utility". That being said, again imagine for example, your inequality predicate on zip code only returned 2 rows for a specific zip code (and in general never returned 5 million rows like your `state` equality predicate does), by having the zip code fields first in your index definition, your query will eliminate all but 2 rows from the first predicate it matches on, the inequality predicate for the zip fields, before it then does additional filtering on `state` which is defined after the `zip_start`, `zip_end`. Anyway again it's futile arguing over it, and you'd really just have to test.

Comment: Note in the above example, if it's not clear, once all but 2 rows have been eliminated by the zip fields predicate, the `state` predicate subsequent filtering happens against **only** those 2 records.

Answer (score 1):

Don't dismiss the simple btree index until you try it.  It surely won't scale well to a trillion rows, but you surely don't have a trillion rows.  It might be good enough.

To use an gist index, you would need to treat the ranges explicitly as ranges, not as end points.  It would probably be best to reformat your table in that format, but you can instead use expression indexes to reformat on the fly.  But then your query will have to be written to match.

Some other complexities are that simple scalars don't have built in gist operators, so to put "state" into a gist index requires you to use the btree_gist extension; and there is not a built-in text range.  Rather than creating a text-range, you can just cast the zip to int (which would probably be better done in the table in the first place), so something like this:

```
create index on regions using gist(
  state,
  daterange(date_begin,date_end,'[]'),
  int4range(zip_begin::int,zip_end::int,'[]')
);
```

And then the query would look like:

```
SELECT data
FROM regions
WHERE state = {state}
  AND {date}::date <@ daterange(date_begin,date_end,'[]')
  AND {zip}::int <@ int4range(zip_begin::int,zip_end::int,'[]')
```

<s>Now I haven't tested this query on the gist index, because gist indexes are so ridiculously slow to build that I don't have one available yet to try it on.</s> It has finished building and I have tested it, and it runs and gives the correct answer with '0' left-padded 5 digit zip codes.  With the range sizes I used, it is sometimes faster and some times slower than the btree index on a 10e6 row table, but was never markedly different.

Comment: By casting ZIP from string to a number, you alter the comparison semantics...

Comment: I don't think you do as long as they were zero left padded to start with.  And if they weren't zero left padded, then your comparisons seems rather hosed when done as strings and casting does change it but in a way that is probably for the better.